# JIRA dashboard panel not displaying properly

Tags: jira

[image: JIRA Dashboard]

I have circled in red the problem panel above. It refuses to expand the panel vertically to display the content. I tried recreating the dashboard from scratch, I have no idea what else to try because I don't understand what the problem is in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of console ? (Press F12, click on Console, press Ctrl + L, and hit F5 to refresh the page)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the query behind the gadget is not returning any issues?

[image: edit gadget]:

Comment: No, the issues are there, when I first add the widget the graph displays OK, but navigating back to the dashboard it displays incorrectly.

Comment: So you can go to the url for the saved filter behind this chart and issues show?

Comment: Yeah. You can see the top of the graph in the image. There's data there.

This is still unresolved, btw, I'm just ignoring it.